# formula for surface area without dimensions

Tags: area

If the radius of a cylinder is twice its height, write a formula for the surface area in terms of its height only.

My textbook says the answer is $12\pi h^2,$ but I got a completely different answer if someone could work me through this it would be a great help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_%28geometry%29#Surface_area), $S = 2πrh + 2πr^2$

If $r = 2h$, we can substitute in:
$S = 2πrh + 2πr^2 = 2π(2h)h + 2π(2h)^2 = 4πh^2 + 8πh^2 = 12πh^2$

Answer (score 0):

suppose the height of the cylinder is $h.$ then the radius is $2h$ and the circumference of the cylinder is $2 \pi r =  4\pi h$ the curved surface area is $4 \pi h h = 4\pi h^2$

the lid and the bottom circles have the area twice $\pi (2h)^2 = 4\pi h^2$ all together you have $12 \pi h^2$ in surface area.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r$ denote the radius and $h$ denote the height. If the radius of a cylinder is twice its height, then $r = 2h$.

Now, use the formula
$$
A = 2 \pi r h + 2 \pi r^2
$$
substituting $2h$ for $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote by $R$
  the radius of the cylinder and $h$
  its height : we thus have $2h=R$
 . The area of one disc is $$S_{D}=\pi R^{2}$$
  and the area of the lateral surface is $$S_{L}=2\pi Rh.$$ Thus the total area is $$2S_{D}+S_{l}=2\pi R^{2}+2\pi Rh=8\pi h^{2}+4\pi h^{2}=12\pi h^{2}$$
  as claimed.